# How do I get a Unit Vector Representing the Facing of a Quaternion?

Tags: vectors, quaternions

I have a point that has a rotation, the quaternion $(.5, .5i, .5j, -.5k)$. If I place this at the origin of a unit sphere, how can I project a vector from the origin to the point on the unit sphere that the point is facing?

I tried to find this using the axis of rotation, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not really sure what I'm doing during these operations, or more importantly: why these operations specifically. I'm just randomly attempting things, so I have no confidence my attempts are even remotely in the right direction. I suppose my next attempt would be to take a unit vector and apply the quaternion rotation to it, but that seems to be making the problem more complex.

Is this possible or should I be applying the quaternion to a unit vector? If two things are facing the same way, but one of them is flipped, I expect the two unit vectors to be the same. Being upside down doesn't change the direction the point is facing. (ie. $(.5, .5i, .5j, -.5k)$ and $(.5, -.5i, .5j, .5k)$ would both result in vector $(0x,0y,-1z)$)

I have tried implementing the solution in [How to rotate unit vectors and unit quaternions by unit quaternions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191567/how-to-rotate-unit-vectors-and-unit-quaternions-by-unit-quaternions) but doing those operations with $(.5, -.5i, .5j, .5k)$ is giving me $(−0.25,0.25,−0.25)$

Comment: What does it mean for a point to have a rotation? A quaternion is a four dimensional vector but the unit sphere is in three dimensions.  How do you place the quaternion so that it goes from the origin to a point on the surface of the sphere? You also ask: "how can I project a vector from the origin to the point on the unit sphere that the point is facing?". What does that mean?

Comment: Are you saying that you have some reference (unit) direction $v$ and that direction $w$ of your point is obtained by rotating $v$ by the quaternion $q$? In that case you do exactly that: $w = qvq^{-1}$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff that is equivalent to what I'm saying. Is that the only way?

Comment: @JohnDouma I am wanting to pull out a unit vector based on the way the quaternion faces. Like how the axis of rotation for the four dimensional quaternion is the 3d unit vector of $(w, xi, yj, zk)$ -> $(x, y, z)$, but instead of the axis of rotation I'm looking for the way the point would face.

Comment: @UpTide A quaternion only represents a rotation. You **need** to have the reference direction $v$ involved to get a direction out of a quaternion. What's wrong with $qvq^{-1}$? If you want to you can express it in terms of inner and cross products; indeed, this is usually how the operation $v \mapsto qvq^{-1}$ is implemented in programming languages if given its own function. You could express it in Cartesian components, too.